# form onSubmit not reading return status it seems

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I feel stupid not knowing why this isn't working, seems simple enough.  I have a form and trying to validate it using onSubmit="return validateForm()" however if you submit it with none of the fields that are required filled in which would result in a "false" it is submitting to itself.

Javascript:

```
function validateForm(){
var errorFlag = true;
var fields = $("input.required");
var currFlag = true;
var i;
for(i=0; i < fields.length; i++){
    var myName = $(fields[i]).attr("name");
    if(myName == "payment_method"){
        if($('input[name=payment_method]:checked').val().trim() == "credit card"){
            var ad1 = $("#address").val().trim();
            var adC = $("#city").val().trim();
            var adS = $("#state").val().trim();
            var adZ = $("#zip").val().trim();

            if(ad1 == "" || adC == "" || adS == "" || adZ == ""){
                $("#address-error").addClass("showError");
                errorFlag = false;
            }
        }else{
            $("#address-error").removeClass("showError");
        }
    }else{
        currFlag = checkField($(fields[i]));
        if(!currFlag){
            errorFlag = false;
        }
    }
}
    return errorFlag;
}

function checkField(target){
    var myType = $(target).attr("type");
    var myValue = $(target).val().trim();
    var myName = $(target).attr("name");

    var errorFlag = true;

    if((myType == "text" || myType == "number") && (myValue == "" || myValue == " ")){
    $("#"+myName+"-error").addClass("showError");
        errorFlag = false;
    }else if(myType == "email" && !validateEmail(myValue)){
        $("#"+myName+"-error").addClass("showError");
        errorFlag = false;
    }else{
        $("#"+myName+"-error").removeClass("showError");
        errorFlag = true;
    }

    return errorFlag;
}

function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}
```

The the form consists of text boxes mostly, but there is a set of radio buttons and if the first if statement in validateForm() is hit, meaning the user selected credit card then everything is fine and the form recognizes the return false.  But if they just submit the form with absolutely nothing marked then it just refreshes the page as if it is submitting.

even if I just put "return false;" it still doesn't stop it. It is just very weird.

html of form is below.

```
<form class="span6" name="bookingForm" action="" onSubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
        <section class="grid12">
            <h4 class="span12">Contact Information</h4>
            <div id="first-name-error" class="error span12"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i> Oops it looks like you may have forgotten to fill this out</div>
            <label  class="span12" for="first-name">First Name (required)
                <input class="required" type="text" id="first-name" name="first-name">
            </label>
            <div id="last-name-error" class="error span12"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i> Oops it looks like you may have forgotten to fill this out</div>
            <label class="span12" for="last-name">Last Name (required)
                <input class="required" type="text" id="last-name" name="last-name">
            </label>
            <div id="email-error" class="error span12"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i> The email entered is invalid</div>
            <label class="span12" for="email">Email (required)
                <input class="required" type="email" id="email" name="email">
            </label>
            <label class="span12" for="phone">Phone Number (required for credit card payment)
                <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone">
            </label>
        </section> 
        <section class="grid12">
            <h4 class="span12">Booking Details</h4>
            <div id="arrivalPicker-error" class="error span12"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i> We need to know when you would like to stay</div>
            <label class="span6" for="arrivalPicker">Arrival (required)
                <input class="dateInput required" id="arrivalPicker"  type="text" name="arrivalPicker">
            </label>
            <label class="span6" for="departPicker">Depart (required)
                <input class="dateInput required" id="departPicker" type="text" name="departPicker">
            </label>
            <label  class="span6" for="adults">Number of Adults (required)
                <input class="required" type="number" id="adults" name="adults" value="1" min="1">
            </label>
            <label  class="span6" for="children">Number of Children (required)
                <input type="number" id="children" name="children" min="0" value="0">
            </label>
            <span class="span12"><em>Our condo can hold a maximum occupancy of 6 persons.  You may add 1 extra person but will be charged $30/night from the resort</em></span>
        </section>
        <section class="grid12">
            <h4 class="span12">Preferred Payment Method</h4>
            <p class="span12">We understand the importance of your information.  If choosing "Credit Card by Phone", be assured we do not write down any of your credit card information or keep it for ourselves.  We enter it right into the secured Las Palomas reservation system. If you still have doubts then please feel free to use the more secure bank to bank transfer method.</p>
            <fieldset class="span12">
              <div id="payment-error" class="error span12"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i> We need to know how you would like to pay</div>
              <legend>Choose Your Method</legend>
              <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label for="payment_method">
                      <input class="required" type="radio" id="creditCard" name="payment_method" value="credit card">
                      Credit Card by Phone
                    </label>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <label for="bankTransfer">
                      <input type="radio" id="bankTransfer" name="payment_method" value="bank transfer">
                      Bank Transfer
                    </label>
                  </li>
              </ul>
            </fieldset>
            <div id="address-error" class="error span12"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i> We need your address for credit card transactions</div>
            <label class="span12" for="address">If you chose "Credit Card by Phone" please include your Address below
                <input type="text" id="address" name="address">
            </label>
            <label class="span4" for="city">City
                <input type="text" id="city" name="city">
            </label>
            <label class="span4" for="state">State
                <input type="text" id="state" name="state">
            </label>
            <label class="span4" for="zip">Zip Code
                <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip">
            </label>
        </section>
        <section class="grid12">
            <h4 class="span12">Optional Items</h4>
            <label class="span12" for="hear">How Did You Hear About Us?
                <input type="text" id="hear" name="hear">
            </label>
            <label class="span12" for="comments">Any Comments or Questions?
                <textarea id="comments" name="comments"></textarea>
            </label>
        </section>
        <hr />
        <section class="grid12">
            <label class="span12">
                <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="Yes"> I would like to <strong>sign-up</strong> for your <strong>newsletter</strong><br>(we will only save your name and email address into a secure database for our future newsletter email list, we will NEVER share your contact information)
            </label>
            <div id="first-name-error" class="error span12"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i> We need to have your consent to store your contact information for our newsletter (and only our newsletter)</div>
            <label class="span12">
                <input type="checkbox" name="gdpr" value="I agree"> I consent to having this website store my name and email address in order to add me to their online Newsletter list.<br><br>
            </label>
            <div class="g-recaptcha span12" data-sitekey="6LcW_C0UAAAAAOS1pFLC-A0QhnTvZW8Xi9Yi88z9"></div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Your Inquiry" class="continue">
        </section>
    </form>
```

I will admit I haven't coded in awhile so maybe I made some simple mistake in the form set up.

Comment: Please include your html.

Comment: Just added, also a live link as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to *prevent* the *default* form submission in your function:

```
function validateForm(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
```

And your event listener should look like this:

```
<form onsubmit="validateForm(e)">
```

Comment: In all of my research I have not seen it this way at all. Though if I can't figure it out the regular way using onsubmit="return validateForm()" might have to try it.

Comment: @nonstoprobot May I know which site did you learn this? The native and one of the prevalent ways of attaching event parameters is onsubmit="functionName()".

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp - so your function that you call should either return true or false, "true" and the form goes through.  "False" and it doesn't.  The only way my validation works is if you have the "credit card" radio button selected.

Comment: Ended up just using a version of this answer after trying several more times to get my original to work.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @nonstoprobot No problem whatsoever!